# What did I do wrong in this piece of code - to reverse a string?

Tags: javascript

What did I do wrong in this piece of code - to reverse a string in javascript?

```js
function reverseString(str) {
  var str = .split("").reverse().join();
  return str;
}
console.log(reverseString("hello"));
```

Comment: I am sure the debugger takes you right to the syntax error....

Comment: `str.split("").reverse().join();`, you have missing `str`

Comment: I made it runnable so you can click the run button and see the error right there on the page..... Learn to use your debugger built into the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You miss the variable for splitting and with join, you need an empty string.

```js
function reverseString(str) {
  var str = str.split("").reverse().join("");
  //        ^^^                          ^^
  return str;
}
console.log(reverseString("hello"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving the `.split()` method anything to split. You should be able to just do this:

```
function reverseString(str) {
      return str.split("").reverse().join("");
    }  
    console.log(reverseString("hello"));
```

Comment: Yep, you are right. My bad. Thank you, I removed that comment